# 2D morphing video images

Tags: animation, blend-modes

I'm trying to morph from one video to another. I've seen some tutorial of how to morph images subdividing the plane and moving vertices, but what I really want is to morph from 2D moving images (video) sequence.
Does anyone know of any add-on/pluggin that I can use to accomplish this?

I was thinking about placing a feature request, since I think that the tracking system can be used to greatly automate this task. Does anyone know the right place to do this? Do you think it is an interesting feature to ask for?

I know there are programs that can be used to accomplish this task outside blender. I'm using `gtkmorph` to do the task, but AFAIK I have to morph from still images, and morphing a video sequence becomes very time consuming.

Comment: Using the tracker would be quite simple. Use "Link Empty to Track", then on the 3d vewport use those empties as hooks to deform a plane's geometry.

Comment: @cegaton, that looks promising but how do you merge both videos tracking points and images?

Comment: Morph in what way? Some pictures or videos would do a lot to help us understand what you're after. I can think of a lot of different methods. It depends on what you're specifically trying to do. cegaton's comment is the closest to what I would do in all cases though. If that seems overwhelming, it's because it is hard to do. To do The Rolling Stones video, Michel Gondry employed his brother to help do the programming for things he could not do himself. https://youtu.be/0-jm6qb7hmA?t=20m30s

Comment: @WrayBowling regarding this question I reformulated it as http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38941/interpolate-two-sets-of-tracking-points according to @cegaton´s comment. I finally achieved the effect with `gtkmorph` check minute 3:30 in the next video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8PcW7V9PSY but I would be glad to know if the updated question in the link above has an answer. Thanks.

Comment: In the future, try not to fragment your questions. In all likelihood, now one of the two questions will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @WrayBowling I don't think I fragmented my question. I think they are two different questions even though the goal is the same. If you think they should be closed proceed as you deem appropiate.

Comment: If I'm correct, that would require a grid warp plugin. Perhaps that can be added, but then the question is where does it become an efficient 3D software vs. a motion graphics software? So as a plugin a grid warp would be cool, but I think your comment answers your question since it is a 2D plugin. I'm sure someone can create it (and probably will), but it's suited for a 2D software.

Answer (score 1):

Try image sequence import addon. This makes animated images appear on plane. See this video link here. 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3UOywRFIpLM&feature=youtu.be

Updated addon link: https://github.com/vicentecarro/ImageSequenceAsPlanes

First create image sequence from a video clip. With that addon, import Image sequence and all animated images appear on plane. Subdivide the plane like a lattice. Alternatively use a knife to divide plane's face. When you move vertrice or reshape the plane, the animated image distorts, useful for morphing your way. Hope that helps.

If unsatisfied, try DragonBones, a free open source software.

Comment: Hi @RitaGeraghty, thanks for your answer but the problem here is morphing points of two different planes (remember I want to morph from two videos) AND mixing images as they blend and transform.

Comment: That is going to be tricky. You can get away with Gimp's morphing GAP tool. Take screenshots of two video clips. GAP in Gimp lets you morph two photos and do image sequence of that.  After that, you can import image sequence and sandwich it between two video clips. https://youtu.be/WCiYSiHKfO0

Comment: If I can remember, I tried Gimp but rather prefered gtkmorph which is what I finally used for the job. I just thought it would be nice to have that functionality in Blender.