# Is there a way to "pin" a vertex to a tracking point?

Tags: modifiers, tracking

I am looking for a way to pin a vertex to a tracking point.

I tried using hooks but it seems that the vertex moves relatively to its original position by a vector equal to the location of the empty instead of matching the global coordinates of the empty.

[image]