# Mapping/texturing inside of a box

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to replace the content of a box in a video, I have used the tracking system to match the movement of the video box with the interior of the one rendered in Blender, but I am running trough what seems a simple thing but I can't manage to get done.

I want the outside faces of the box to be invisible while hiding the inside of the box where the front wall of the box hides it, and the inside of the box to be rendered where visible. To do that I thought it would be as simple as making the face normals point to the inside of the box and giving a color only to the faces where normals are pointing to. But I can't manage to get that, am I going the wrong road? How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***CYCLES RENDER***

To give a texture only to the inside of the box you may use a ***Backfacing*** output of the ***Geometry*** node.
[image]

Unwrap your mesh and set the nodes as pictured below. Use a ***Backfacing*** output as a factor for two materials/textures.
[image]

---

***BLENDER RENDER***

In *Blender Internal* you may also use the material nodes to achieve this effect.
[image]

Unwrap your mesh and give it a new material. Check the *Use Shader Nodes* box.
[image]

Now add two other materials- one for the inside and one for the outside of the box.
[image]

In the *Node Editor* window set up the nodes as pictured below.
[image]

You may also add just one material and create two others within it using nodes. Unwrap your mesh and add a new material. Check the *Use Shader Nodes* box.
[image]

Set up the material nodes as pictured below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Gonzou, couldn't it be achieved without nodes? I'm trying to stick to Blender Render instead of Cycles.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use nodes in BI too to achieve this effect :). Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Great!!!! thank you very much, I'll let you see the final composite when I have it finished, it is just a box opening and smoke coming out of it (inside will be erased/replaced and smoke added with Blender's physics) :P

Comment: @YoMismo, I'm glad I helped :D. Waiting for the link with your finished project. Happy blending mate :).

Comment: I have finally finished the video. The inside of the box didn't have to be replaced since the smoke covered all the things that were inside and didn't have to be seen, so only a transparent material has been used to be able to use the box as a collision. Here is the link (don't laugh too much it is just a hobby for me & wife), skip to minute 3:27. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8PcW7V9PSY

Comment: It's nice to see you and your wife have fun making movies :). Too bad I don't understand spanish. The smoke and sand simulations look very nice. BTW How you achieved the morph effect? Looks cool.

Comment: thanks :D. Regarding the morph effect, I opened two questions here trying to achieve it with Blender (http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38760/2d-morphing-video-images  and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38941/interpolate-two-sets-of-tracking-points) but with no luck. Finally I used gtk-morph, it's a great piece of software to do exactly that, the only problem is that you can't morph videos and I had to do the job by hand (extract video to images and morph individually), it took time, but the effect looks nice. Thanks again for your kind words mate ;)