# How to apply a texture to only one side of a plane

Tags: texturing

How can you have an image as a texture (in this case on cloth) that is only applied to one side of a plane?

I would like the reverse side to be a solid color.

Please see below image where the cloth has the image texture on both sides.

[image: current double sided plane]

Comment: Which render engine, Cycles or Blender Render?

Comment: Slightly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39236/mapping-texturing-inside-of-a-box

Answer (score 8):

In *Cycles* you may use a ***Backfacing*** output of the ***Geometry*** node as a factor for applying two materials for each side of a plane. Set up the material nodes as pictured below. You may do it in the same way in *Blender Internal*. The only difference is in *BI* the output of the ***Geometry*** node is called ***Front/Back***.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Material Node Compositor

Add > Input > Geometry

### Blender Internal

Plug the **Front/Back** socket to the Fac socket of the Mix Node

[image]

### Cycles

Plug the **Backfacing** socket to the Fac socket of the Mix Shader

[image]