# How to make this dress animatable with White on top and Green on the bottom?

Tags: animation, materials, physics, faces

I'm at an impasse here, I'm making the dress part of Gardevoir[image: The Dress with Properties] where the inner(green) and outer(white) faces will be visible, But i am also trying to use Cloth physics to animate the dress as well. But so far none of my own methods have yielded any satisfying results. One where creating the faces for the bottom part so each can have its own color would cause horrible clipping when put to the physics.

I really need help with this. I could just keep the single color and call it a day, but no, I really need to know how to do this for any future projects.

Comment: Sounds like you need to do something like this http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39601/29586

Comment: Ok, this is what i was looking for, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cycles materials you can use the Backfacing output of the Geometry node to mix different shaders on the inside and outside of a surface. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39601/29586