# Two-sided clothing with different materials?

Tags: materials, normals, cloth-simulation

How do I make two-sided clothing using the Cloth modifier, such that the front and back have different materials?

Comment: Very related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39599/how-to-apply-a-texture-to-only-one-side-of-a-plane

Answer (score 4):

In cycles, you can use the backfacing as a mixing factor between shaders.

[image: Node Tree]

In internal, you can use the front/back as a mixing factor between materials.

[image: Node Tree 2]