# How do I make a UV unwapped image visible on only one side of the object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I UV unwrapped a label and applied a texture.  However,the back side needs be a solid color. I applied the following suggestions 
[How to apply a texture to only one side of a plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39599/how-to-apply-a-texture-to-only-one-side-of-a-plane). As you can see from the screen shot it is not working for me. Why?[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at outliner you have some modifiers on the object. Is there solidify? If yes that would explain it. Enabling *Only Rim* option on it would fix it.

Comment: That did the trick. For those that don't know, in this instance you will find the -Only Rim- option In the solidify modifiers panel.

Comment: If you do want to use a full solidify, you can provide a material index offset-- this will look down the object's material list, n number of entries, to provide a different material for the rim and/or other side, via which you can have the other side use whatever material you want.

Answer (score 1):

Jaroslav Jerryno Novotn answered my question in the comments section. I did indeed have a solidify modifier on the object and as suggested, I enabled the Only Rim option in the solidify modifiers panel. This worked for me.

Comment: Please don't post text as an image. Text in an image cannot be searched and indexed by search engines and cannot be edited. Instead, write a proper answer (as text) and give credit to those who helped you.

Comment: Sorry @cegaton. I thought I was being helpful! I will change it!