# Rendering flipped textured backface

Tags: texturing, faces

I have a scene where I render many falling tickets which consists of a textured plane with some text on. Currently, since it is a single face, the text on the backface is flipped. Is there any way to render both faces un-flipped? Or is the only option to have two faces?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a texture to only one side of a plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39599/how-to-apply-a-texture-to-only-one-side-of-a-plane)

Comment: I don’t think this is strictly a duplicate as it’s specifically asking for *flipped* image on the other side while the linked answers are for *different materials* on each side. Technically not much difference, I know. I think it would be worthwhile an answer dealing specifically with this (flipping the coordinates based on Backfacing). I can’t do this right now so if anyone wants to oblige...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Geometry node provides a Backfacing value that indicates whether the front or back face is being rendered. By using this to mix between the normal image coordinates and coordinates which have been scales by -1 in one direction we can effectively flip the image for the opposite face, "unmirroring" the image so that the same image is shown on the front and back.

This can be achieved with the following nodes :

[image: nodes]

Note the Mapping node with the Y-scale set to -1. The Mix node selects which set of input coordinates (Generated or the 'flipped' generated) are used to drive the Image Texture.

---

Additional...

This only works 'as-is' due to the Image Texture being set to 'Repeat'. The 'unflipped' coordinates vary in the Y coordinate from 0.0 to 1.0 and so the mapping node is translating this to 0.0 to **-**1.0 - ie, the opposite to the usual coordinates. Since the Image Texture is set to 'Repeat' this isn't a problem since the image repeats in all directions.

In order to allow this to work with 'Clipped' images you can simply use the Location settings of the Mapping node to offset Y by 1.0 (set 'Y' Location to 1.0). This will translate the 0.0 to -1.0 values to 1.0 to 0.0 (ie, reversed).

Answer (score 0):

[image: image texture rotate]

Maybe you can create an extruded face at the same (or slightly different, if some thickness is allowed) z location. And then add image texture on the two faces. The rotation can be adjusted by adding a mapping and a texture coordinate node.

Comment: Additional geometry may require more resources and is not required. Check the links above