# how to add siding to exterior of building

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

If I have a building and the walls are one object, is it possible to make the front exterior wall have a stone texture and the back exterior wall horizontal metal siding, for example? Likewise on an interior room can there be painted walls and a wall papered accent wall if the room's walls are a single object? How are these examples achieved? So far it appears to me that if I assign a material and texture to an object the whole object is affected. How is it possible to apply a different material/texture to a surface of the object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply a texture to only one side of a plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39599/how-to-apply-a-texture-to-only-one-side-of-a-plane/39601#39601) or [How can I make a material only apply to a side of a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a material only apply to a side of a plane?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/how-can-i-make-a-material-only-apply-to-a-side-of-a-plane)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In edit mode select the ominous faces and assign material for them.